# how to process hits on lucene 3.03

Tags: c#, lucene.net

```
List<SearchResults> Searchresults = new List<SearchResults>();

    // Specify the location where the index files are stored
    string indexFileLocation = @"D:\Lucene.Net\Data\Persons";

    Lucene.Net.Store.Directory dir = FSDirectory.Open(indexFileLocation);
    // specify the search fields, lucene search in multiple fields
    string[] searchfields = new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName", "DesigName", "CatagoryName" };
    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);
    // Making a boolean query for searching and get the searched hits
    Query som = QueryMaker(searchString, searchfields);
    int n = 1000;
    TopDocs hits = indexSearcher.Search(som,null,n);



    for (int i = 0; i <hits.TotalHits; i++)
    {
        SearchResults result = new SearchResults();
        result.FirstName = hits.ScoreDocs.GetValue(i).ToString();

        result.FirstName = hits.Doc.GetField("FirstName").StringValue();
        result.LastName = hits.Doc(i).GetField("LastName").StringValue();
        result.DesigName = hits.Doc(i).GetField("DesigName").StringValue();
        result.Addres = hits.Doc(i).GetField("Addres").StringValue();
        result.CatagoryName = hits.Doc(i).GetField("CatagoryName").StringValue();
        Searchresults.Add(result);
    }
```

i have table fields first name last name .... how can i process hit to get the values from the search result

> i have an error that says TopDocs does not contain defination for doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lean on the compiler. There is no property or method called `Doc` in `TopDocs` class. In `ScoreDocs` property of `TopDocs` class you have list of hits with document number and score. You need to use this document number to get actual document. After that use method `Doc` which is in `IndexSearcher` to query for document with this number. And then you can get stored field data from that document.

You can process results like that:

```
foreach (var scoreDoc in hits.ScoreDocs)
{
    var result = new SearchResults();
    var doc = indexSearcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc);
    result.FirstName = doc.GetField("FirstName").StringValue;
    result.LastName = doc.GetField("LastName").StringValue;
    result.DesigName = doc.GetField("DesigName").StringValue;
    result.Addres = doc.GetField("Addres").StringValue;
    result.CategoryName = doc.GetField("CategoryName").StringValue;
    Searchresults.Add(result);
}
```

Or in more `LINQ` way:

```cs
var searchResults = 
    indexSearcher
    .Search(som, null, n)
    .ScoreDocs
    .Select(scoreDoc => indexSearcher.Doc(scoreDoc))
    .Select(doc =>
    {
        var result = new SearchResults();
        result.FirstName = doc.GetField("FirstName").StringValue;
        result.LastName = doc.GetField("LastName").StringValue;
        result.DesigName = doc.GetField("DesigName").StringValue;
        result.Addres = doc.GetField("Addres").StringValue;
        result.CategoryName = doc.GetField("CategoryName").StringValue;
        return result;
     })
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Separation of `hits` method will let you clear the matched `documents` and in future if you want to `highlight` the matched `documents` then you can easily embed the `lucene.net highlighter` in `getMatchedHits` method.

```
List<SearchResults> Searchresults = new List<SearchResults>();

// Specify the location where the index files are stored
string indexFileLocation = @"D:\Lucene.Net\Data\Persons";

Lucene.Net.Store.Directory dir = FSDirectory.Open(indexFileLocation);
        // specify the search fields, lucene search in multiple fields
string[] searchfields = new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName", "DesigName", "CatagoryName" };
IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);
// Making a boolean query for searching and get the searched hits
Query som = QueryMaker(searchString, searchfields);
int n = 1000;
var hits = indexSearcher.Search(som,null,n).ScoreDocs;

Searchresults = getMatchedHits(hits,indexSearcher);
```

**getMatchedHits** method code:

```
public static List<SearchResults> getMatchedHits(ScoreDoc[] hits, IndexSearcher searcher)
{
   List<SearchResults> list = new List<SearchResults>();
   SearchResults obj;
   try
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < hits.Count(); i++)
        {
          // get the document from index
          Document doc = searcher.Doc(hits[i].Doc);
          string strFirstName  = doc.Get("FirstName");
          string strLastName = doc.Get("LastName");
          string strDesigName = doc.Get("DesigName");
          string strAddres  = doc.Get("Addres");
          string strCategoryName = doc.Get("CategoryName");
          obj = new SearchResults();
          obj.FirstName = strFirstName;
          obj.LastName = strLastName;
          obj.DesigName= strDesigName;
          obj.Addres = strAddres;
          obj.CategoryName = strCategoryName;
          list.Add(obj);
       }
       return list;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       return null; // or throw exception
     }
}
```

Hope it Helps!